# Missing float during WAV decode

Tags: python, wav

I'd like to decode a wav file (coded in 4 bytes) into list of decimal. Here is my code :

```
size = struct.calcsize("dfff1fffffff1")
s = struct.Struct("dfff1fffffff1")
su = s.unpack(fichier.read(size))
```

My output let me read 1 "bad" decimal and 11 "good" one. (the bad is always the same, example: `(0.007812501848093234, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` (my signal is 1 or -1 : [download](https://mega.nz/#!Q1wm0IaB!-YJsZslAb1CKDhIWNRIoZ04zeXSbQh8AlA3UojKOnIs))

Do you know why?

Comment: Why not just use the `wave` module? It is standard…

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It is not  necessary to "sign" your posts (and actually unwanted). Your name is already under each of your posts with your profile picture. What is the URL supposed to provide? I get an `An error occurred while loading MEGA`. Also please note that in English there is no space before end-of-sentence punctuation.

Comment: Hi, it's a mega link, it's fully working for me. Try again : https://mega.nz/#!Q1wm0IaB!-YJsZslAb1CKDhIWNRIoZ04zeXSbQh8AlA3UojKOnIs